# Xamarin, Animation via XML: Hand over a vari

Tags: android, animation, xamarin

I am having an animated slider via XML in my code:

```
    private void MoveSlider()
    {
        if (blNewestSelected)
        {
            var moveIt = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this.BaseContext, 
                Resource.Animation.Profile_MoveSliderToLeft);
            btnItemSelected.StartAnimation(moveIt);
        }
        else if (blMostApSelected)
        {
            var moveIt = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this.BaseContext, 
                Resource.Animation.Profile_MoveSliderToCenter);
            btnItemSelected.StartAnimation(moveIt);
        }
        else if (blMostUpvotedSelected)
        {
            var moveIt = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this.BaseContext, 
                Resource.Animation.Profile_MoveSliderToRight);
            btnItemSelected.StartAnimation(moveIt);
        }

    }
```

The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">
  <translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:toXDelta="62%p"
    android:duration="400" />

</set>
```

The problem is, that the animation always starts at 0 x-delta.
I need to however hand over a varibale of the current delta, so that
the animation starts from where the object currently is and not ALWAYS from 0.
I have not been able to find out, how to do that. It is probably pretty easy...
Any help be awesome :)

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ObjectAnimation` which actually moves an object. This works fine, but you need to target your app for minimum API level 11 :

```
IInterpolator interpolators = AnimationUtils.LoadInterpolator(this, Android.Resource.Interpolator.AccelerateDecelerate);

ObjectAnimator transAnimation = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(view, propertyName, fromX, toX);
transAnimation.SetDuration(400);
transAnimation.SetInterpolator(interpolators);
transAnimation.Start();
```

**view**  - this is the view on which animation is to be applied

**propertyName** - The property being animated, for your situation is **"translationX"**.

**FromX,toX** -  A set of values that the animation will animate between over time.